# How to deal with bad quality when scaling/resizing images in Internet explorer

Tags: image, internet-explorer, resize

I have .gif images which are 96*96 and they have transparency. They are not animated.

All I want to do is showing these images on a page with 32*32 sizes. I simply do:

```
<img src="{path}" width="32" height="32"/>
```

In Chrome it looks good, in Firefox not bad, in Internet Explorer terrible.
Internet explorer totally ruins the quality of the image.

My question is if there is a way of dealing with this problem? Any css tips?
All I have got from my search is `-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;` but it didn't work.

If you do not have any CSS solutions, can you give me an example of resizing a .gif image which has transparency to size 32*32. When I try it, I either lose transparency or ruinning the quality and all the examples about resizing images via GD is about .png or .jpg files. I have .gif files and they have transparency.